# Messaging API(MAPI) acces via Qt

Tags: c++, qt, desktop-application, desktop, mapi

Does Qt have some Messaging API(MAPI) interface?
I have C++/Qt program and want to send email via message client (it could be Outlook or any messaging-type program "email client") but can't find module in Qt library to manage the process.
Could you please help me? Thanks.

Comment: You may find this useful instead of MAPI with Qt: https://github.com/bluetiger9/SmtpClient-for-Qt

Comment: AlexanderVX Thanks for the help but this is not what I actually need.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the help! Today I found the solution. Maybe it will help someone in the future. So for sending Emails via Message Client on Desktop Machines you should use [QDesktopServices](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl) module.